# Plotting Long and Latitude in R

Tags: r, google-maps, plot, ggplot2, maps

I would like to know how to plot latitude and longitude readings in R.
Drive Route:

[image]

I want something like the above image. The route is for a street in Nigeria and the lat/long readings were obtained from a GPS. The plot was done with MapInfo but I would appreciate if someone can show me how it is done in R. I am still a newbie in R.

Comment: You have to research a bit, and ask question here more specific. This isn't the place to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andy on doing some more research before asking questions, but to get you started I would suggest you have a look at the `ggplot2` and `ggmap` package combination. Which can be used to set up maps and plot gps locations on these maps.

I mainly use it to plot sample locations, but I guess you could also use it to plot routes/lines.